# Eclipse: Java Build Path is missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to use Google's SDK Tutorial for Android using Eclipse.  I was able to get the first two projects to work, but when running the third R.java disappeared so I gave up on that.

I made a brand new package out of the solution set for exercise 3.  It was full of errors, like files being in src/com/android... instead of com/android.  I fixed that, but it still wouldn't build.

I went to the project -> properties -> Java Build Path, but Eclipse throws an error: "The currently displayed page contains invalid values." It then doesn't load up that window at all.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I import this project properly?

Comment: 1st - R.Java disappeared if your project contains any error. It will be generated automatically when you build your project....Can you post the screen shot of your project path...?

Comment: Sure, if you can tell me where to find it. 
Sorry to be dense, but I'm not used to a full-blown IDE that holds my hand so much. :)

Comment: Open the eclipse...go to project explorer..screen shot those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `Window>Preference>Android>sdk` location  --- is set to be the path of android sdk and if it not works then please go with new eclipse software delete previous check jdk is install and after that set correct android sdk location to above path.

Thanks

Comment: I guess I'm gonna need to re-install. Dang. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

If the first two projects still work, then your studio is probably deployed properly.

You might want to check if you have a build target set.

Right click on project->android->target name.

Otherwise, might make sense to re-download eclipse and reinstall the google adt plugin.