# Problems including library project into build path

Tags: android, project, buildpath

I am trying to follow the steps of setting up a v7 support library as they are listed on the android development website.
[Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

I get stuck on step 5 where I am supposed to right click the JAR files and choose "Build Path". This option is missing. I have checked other questions related to this such as this one>>> [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986411/eclipse-java-build-path-is-missing)

but none of the listed solutions seem to work for me. Either that or I do not see the options that the posters are referring to on the menus. Has anyone had this problem? Where did I go wrong?

I need this for an android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing in eclipse, then you can go to ProjectName -> Right click on it -> Goto `Properties` -> Goto `Java Build Path` -> Go to `Library` -> Choose `Add Jars` option if jar is in same project or choose `Add External JARs` if jar is outside the project folder.

If you have already copied the `JAR` file to `libs/` directory of your project then choose the option of `Add JARs` and browse to the `libs` folder where you've copied the jar. Select it and press okay. It should get included in your project. Hope this helps else please comment.

Comment: I followed your directions and the 'add jar' option appears to be grayed out and the files are already in the library tab underneath 'Android Dependencies'. So this means that they have already been added right? Or do the jar files have to be on the same level as the 'Android 4.2.2.' and 'Android Dependencies' folders?

Comment: If its already in 'Android Dependencies' then its already been included.

Comment: Which error? I think you already seem to have included the JAR in your project. So you can go ahead and run it. is there anything else that you were looking for?

Comment: When I run the program, I see an error that says:
"Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!" Somehow even though I have added the library, it is still not finding a certain file

Comment: I see android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in the support library project but I do not see the apk file. Where can I find this?

Comment: The program builds and runs, I just see a message in red on the console that says that it cannot find the apk file

Comment: Apk file is generated of the whole project and in in the `bin/` directory. Also you generating a apk first select the project, then clean the project by going in `Properties -> Clean` on the top bar in your eclipse. Then also select `Build Automatically` from there. I hope that before running you run `Build`.

Comment: I am using eclipse. When I right click on the project folder and click properties I do not see a clean option. Also how do I build the project without running it in eclipse?

Comment: Ok Nevermind I figured out how to clean the projects and build them without running them. I am still seeing the error message although my application runs. I dont know know why though